# Why aren't canaries useful in structs?

Tags: c

We are studying the use of the canaries to avoid buffer overflow.

There is a question that is:

Why aren't canaries useful in this struct?

```
struct test {
char arra[64];
int myVar;
}
```

and I'm stuck on it. Any clue?

Pd. This is homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your professor means it will not protect (for sure) from overflow of the *array* within your structure. The compiler places the canary value somewhere between your structure and the end of the stack. If you overflow your array by less than int bytes, the overflow corrupts the int element of your structure, not the canary value (this is not precise because of compiler chosen structure layout). So in such cases an overflow goes undetected and could be exploited.

Answer (score 1):

Canaries should be placed in such a way that when the buffer overflows, the first data to get corrupted should be the canary so that we can perform a verification check on the value of canary and set an alert of an overflow according. But in this case I can do something like this without even modifying the value of canary `myVar`.

```
struct test t;
t.arra[100] = 1;
```

[More about Canaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#Canaries)

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about [stack canaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow). I had not until now heard of the term. As I understand it, you would put the int myVar before the char array, but in the WikiPedia example, it's a float.

Why not turn on bounds checking? Although the program will run slower, bounds checking That's in the C compiler isn't it?

Comment: Bound checking cannot easily be reconciled with C's pervasive use of pointer arithmetic. You must be thinking of another language.